# Is it okay to say "that which"?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, phrases

I know that there are certain times to use "that" (for restricting the noun) and certain times to use "which" (for adding information).

How about "that which"?:

> Truth is **that which** conforms to reality.

"That" is here a demonstrative pronoun, but it seems that this usage of *which* is incorrect.

Is this okay?

If it's not correct, how could I restate that sentence?

Comment: Yes, of course. It's a non-specific demonstrative pronoun (_that_) -- meaning _whatever_ -- that is modified by a restrictive relative clause (_which conforms to reality_). A very common construction, often contracted into a headless relative clause as in _Truth is whatever conforms with reality_.

Comment: I like "whatever." But isn't there a [rule](http://goo.gl/8AMLO)?

Comment: @SimonKuang No. There isn’t.  A rule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is absolutely OK to use **'that which'** in that way.

Reference: My favourite quote:

> **That which does not kill us makes us stronger**

Friedrich Nietzsche