# Can I use "which" and "that" together?

Tags: which-that

> I love everybody, but it is your ignorance that which I cannot stand.

Can I say ***that which*** in the statement I made?

Comment: Can I use _that which_ in the statement? Yes if you word it thus: _I love everybody, but that which I cannot stand is your ignorance_

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118152/is-it-okay-to-say-that-which another question

Answer (score 1):

No. The correct form of the sentence would be

> I love everybody, but it is your ignorance that I cannot stand.

Comment: "That which I cannot stand..." what? Not sure what your point is here. Also, could you explain why you down voted my answer?

Comment: Okay... but that's a different sentence. I didn't think the question was "please reword this sentence to include the phrase *that which*", it was "is the phrase *that which* correct in this sentence?".

Comment: @mplungjan The Title (as amended by Andrew) and the question actually say subtly different things. The original version shows that the OP asked the question that toryan answered.

Comment: Ok, removed my downvote - you can however still use that which if you reword to  _I love everybody, but that which I cannot stand is your ignorance_

Comment: Hmm. Sorry; I thought the question title was better than "Can I say this?" and any ambiguity is resolved by the detailed question later on. Maybe not. But SE is collaborative: anyone can edit/rollback or suggest edits/flag for rollback.